# Schedule management optimizer

Tags: memory-management, scheduling

I had this idea of program tohelp me in my everyday life. We both work and don't live in the same city. I was wondering how to make a program that calculate, depending on the work scheduleand the number of travel required between both our house, the best way to spend our weekend, like at which house we have to be and when to spend the maximum time together. I know this sound like a problem you'd get in a school book but i really cant think of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of literature on scheduling, as it is a very important topic. You'd need to make your problem more precise, in particular define your objective and any restictions on the tasks. Note that most such problems are NP complete (no efficient solution likely).

I'd guess that some sort of brute force search is possible, or some sort of dynamic programming solution (but it seems that the restricted subproblems arising are different).